# Android gradle androidDependencies implement， Not only use this command

Tags: android, gradle, groovy

I know a command 'gradle androidDependencies' in android. That show this project dependencies tree. output like this.

```
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1@aar
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0-alpha1@jar
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-alpha1@aar
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0-alpha1@aar
```

I want to know, how it works? where is the gradle read config(lib dependences).

The object is I want to write a script code show the project lib dependences （json format）, I do not want use format command output log. Any none can help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At last I find answer, so I show the code here.

```
private checkPublishVersionName(def pom) {
for (org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration configuration : configurations) {
    DependencySet dependencies = configuration.allDependencies;
    for (Dependency dependency : dependencies) {
        String libNameVersion = dependency.group + ":" + dependency.name + ":" + dependency.version
        if (pom.version.contains("SNAPSHOT")) {
            println "-----------> 依赖库：" + libNameVersion
        } else { // 构造一个异常
            if (libNameVersion.contains("SNAPSHOT")) {
                println "请修正依赖库：" + libNameVersion
                println "-----------> release 包不能有对 snapshot 的依赖。"
                throw new PublishException("---> release 包不能有对 snapshot 的依赖。" + "请修正依赖库：" + libNameVersion)
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```